# deny to make new changes to form if it is not saved

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a form where I have a text input, radio buttons and a select.

What I want is to be able to select the radio button only once and only one option at a time and if I select either of the two again I want the code to not allow it, only in case the data has been saved with the button 'guardar cambios'.

This is because every option changes an image for another and I only want one image to change at a time and after that, send the data to a table.

```js
if (!$('input[id^="prest"').is(":checked")) {
  $('select').attr('disabled', true)
  $('textarea').attr('disabled', true)
  $('.obserSelect').attr('disabled', true)
}
$('input[id^="prest"').on('click', function() {
  $('select[id$="Select"]').attr('disabled', false)
  $('textarea').attr('disabled', false)
  $('.obserSelect').attr('disabled', false)

})

$('input[id^="d"]').prop('disabled', true)
$('input[id$="Color"]').prop('disabled', true)
$('input[name="colorPrestacion"').prop('disabled', true)

$("#paciente").keyup(function() {
  var valPac = $(this).val();
  if ($(valPac !== 0)) {
    $('input[id^="d"]').prop('disabled', false)
    $('input[id$="Color"]').prop('disabled', false)
    $('input[name="colorPrestacion"').prop('disabled', false)

  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card tarjetaDatos">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h5>Ingrese los datos del odontograma</h5>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="tratamientos">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione paciente
            <div class="m-1"></div>
            <input class=" pacInput" autocomplete="off" list="browsers" name="paciente" id="paciente">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione el tipo de Prest. requerida
            <div class="form-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="prestExistente" name="colorPrestacion" value='rojo'>
              <div class="mr-1"></div>
              <font style="color:red"> Prestaciones existentes</font>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="radio" id="prestRequerida" name="colorPrestacion" value='azul'>
                <font style="color:blue"> Prestaciones requeridas</font>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione referencia
            <select class="form-control" name="tratamientos" id="tratSelect">
              <option value='none' selected disabled>Seleccione referencia</option>
              <option value="1">Obturación/caries</option>
              <option value="2">Corona</option>
              <option value="3">Puente</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " style="width:100%">Guardar cambios</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Could someone give me any idea of how to make this? thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to say this seems like bad user experience design. And not quite sure is this even a wanted result:

```
$("[name='colorPrestacion']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='colorPrestacion']").prop('disabled', true);
});
$("#tratSelect").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
$("button[type='submit']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='colorPrestacion']").prop('disabled', false).prop('checked', false);
  $("#tratSelect").prop('disabled', false).prop("selectedIndex", 0);
});
```

This will on radio check and on selecting option put both of those to disabled, and reset after button click. You should at least put the general reset button to reset all if user changes his made without saving...

```js
if (!$('input[id^="prest"').is(":checked")) {
  $('select').attr('disabled', true)
  $('textarea').attr('disabled', true)
  $('.obserSelect').attr('disabled', true)
}
$('input[id^="prest"').on('click', function() {
  $('select[id$="Select"]').attr('disabled', false)
  $('textarea').attr('disabled', false)
  $('.obserSelect').attr('disabled', false)

})

$('input[id^="d"]').prop('disabled', true)
$('input[id$="Color"]').prop('disabled', true)
$('input[name="colorPrestacion"').prop('disabled', true)

$("#paciente").keyup(function() {
  var valPac = $(this).val();
  if ($(valPac !== 0)) {
    $('input[id^="d"]').prop('disabled', false)
    $('input[id$="Color"]').prop('disabled', false)
    $('input[name="colorPrestacion"').prop('disabled', false)

  }
})

$("[name='colorPrestacion']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='colorPrestacion']").prop('disabled', true);
});
$("#tratSelect").on("click", function() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
$("button[type='submit']").on("click", function() {
  $("[name='colorPrestacion']").prop('disabled', false).prop('checked', false);
  $("#tratSelect").prop('disabled', false).prop("selectedIndex", 0)
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">




<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card tarjetaDatos">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-title d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h5>Ingrese los datos del odontograma</h5>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div id="tratamientos">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione paciente
            <div class="m-1"></div>
            <input class=" pacInput" autocomplete="off" list="browsers" name="paciente" id="paciente">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione el tipo de Prest. requerida
            <div class="form-inline">
              <input type="radio" id="prestExistente" name="colorPrestacion" value='rojo'>
              <div class="mr-1"></div>
              <font style="color:red"> Prestaciones existentes</font>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <input type="radio" id="prestRequerida" name="colorPrestacion" value='azul'>
                <font style="color:blue"> Prestaciones requeridas</font>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            Seleccione referencia
            <select class="form-control" name="tratamientos" id="tratSelect">
              <option value='none' selected disabled>Seleccione referencia</option>
              <option value="1">Obturación/caries</option>
              <option value="2">Corona</option>
              <option value="3">Puente</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary " style="width:100%">Guardar cambios</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but can I ask why do you say it is a bad user experience? maybe it seems like that because I don't show the whole code. Your answer works but the select option opens and get disabled at the same time, I changed the click for change there.

Comment: @luz yeah change can work too (BTW in Firefox it worked properly on click). And maybe that is the case, I don't see the whole code, but generally  denying user too change his mind before saving/submitting is bad UX in my opinion.

Comment: ohh I understand I will keep it in mind.Maybe an undo will work?

Comment: @luz Like I mentioned some reset or like you sad undo button as an option would kind of fix that. Aldo I don't understand the full problem of "This is because every option changes an image for another", anyway point is as few restrictions like this on user as possible is wanted, all problems should be dealt  "behind the scenes" programmatically. Anyway it was just a suggestion.

Comment: this is a sample of what I mean so you understand the thing about the images, you have to click one after select an option https://codepen.io/luzsdx/pen/ExKqwXP

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom should work

```
$('input[name="colorPrestacion"]').on('change',function(){
        $('input[name="colorPrestacion"]').attr('disabled',true);
      })
      $('#tratSelect').on('change',function(){
        $('#tratSelect').attr('disabled',true)
      })
      
      $('button[type="submit"]').on('click',function(){
        if($('input[name="colorPrestacion"]').val() && $('#tratSelect').val()){
             $('input[name="colorPrestacion"').prop('disabled', false)
        }
      })
```